# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While deserializing JSON feed , Using OdatajClient

Tags: java, json, odata

I keep running into a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While deserializing JSON feed

Whenever I run this function inside a JUnit test. Any Ideas what could be causing the issue

```
public ODataEntity getInvoicedOrderDetails(Long orderNumber) {

ODataURIBuilder uriBuilder = new ODataURIBuilder(serviceRootUri).appendEntitySetSegment(orders).top(3);

    ODataEntitySetRequest req = ODataRetrieveRequestFactory.getEntitySetRequest(uriBuilder.build());
    req.setFormat(ODataPubFormat.JSON);

    ODataRetrieveResponse<ODataEntitySet> groupResult = req.execute();
    ODataEntitySet result = groupResult.getBody();
    ODataEntity res = result.getEntities().get(0);
    return res ;
}
```

Full Trace from the junit test

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While deserializing JSON feed
at com.msopentech.odatajclient.engine.data.Deserializer.toJSONFeed(Deserializer.java:234)
at com.msopentech.odatajclient.engine.data.Deserializer.toFeed(Deserializer.java:116)
at com.msopentech.odatajclient.engine.data.ODataReader.readEntitySet(ODataReader.java:63)
at com.msopentech.odatajclient.engine.communication.request.retrieve.ODataEntitySetRequest$ODataEntitySetResponseImpl.getBody(ODataEntitySetRequest.java:89)
at com.msopentech.odatajclient.engine.communication.request.retrieve.ODataEntitySetRequest$ODataEntitySetResponseImpl.getBody(ODataEntitySetRequest.java:61)
at com.sbu.orderLookup.orderLookup.getInvoicedOrderDetails(orderLookup.java:43)
at com.sbu.orderLookup.orderLookupTest.retrieveInvoiceNumberTest(orderLookupTest.java:35)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Items" (class com.msopentech.odatajclient.engine.data.json.JSONFeed), not marked as ignorable (4 known properties: , "value", "odata.count", "odata.nextLink", "odata.metadata"])
at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@6616b9; line: 1, column: 11] (through reference chain: com.msopentech.odatajclient.engine.data.json.JSONFeed["Items"])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:79)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:555)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:708)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1160)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:315)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:121)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2080)
at com.msopentech.odatajclient.engine.data.Deserializer.toJSONFeed(Deserializer.java:232)
... 31 more
```

Comment: If you could post the full stack trace, that would be great.

Comment: Just added it any ideas ?

Comment: Check the inner exception.